# Setting up UPS monitoring

Tags: ups

I have acquired a second hand Uninterrupted Power Supply (UPS) that I have refurbished (new battery) and hope to use with my Ubuntu 12.10 system. It's a SOLA 330 with serial out.

I have installed NUT Metapackage and NUT Monitor from Software Centre, but am not sure how to go about setting it all up. A Google search brings up several ways of configuring Network UPS Tools (NUT) or HAL-Drivers, however, HAL-Drivers appears to be obsolete and many commands and config files mentioned to edit do not exist in 12.10 or the current version of NUT (most articles are a few years old). One tutorial seemed to work except the `Error: no UPS definitions found in ups.conf` even though `ups.conf` has values in it as laid out in the tutorial.

How do I go about setting my system to monitor the UPS for a shut down signal? Also, is there a command to determine the UPS is communicating through the serial connection and on what port (to help with setup and configuring, eg. `/dev/ttyS0` is mentioned in one of the tutorials I read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found some very helpful sites that got me going. The one I found most helpful was on [Linux.com](http://www.linux.com) (http://archive09.linux.com/feature/128099). I Initially set everything up verbatim as per the example except my system keeps it's config files in `/etc/nut` (instead of `/etc/ups`). Also, [networkupstools.org](http://www.networkupstools.org) (http://www.networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html) helped me select the correct driver name for my UPS model. After making the necessary changes in the config files I had to use the command `service nut start` (instead of `service ups start`) to start the daemon. I found most of the other commands didn't work, however after a restart Nut Monitor now detects the UPS Daemon running and displays it's details!